# How can I get curses installed for CentOS 6.10 with Python3.6.4?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, python-curses

I have a CentOS 6.10 installation where I have done an alternate install of Python 3.6.4.

When I activate the virtual environment and attempt to run my program, I receive the following error on attempting to import curses:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

I've attempted to locate the correct curses and install with pip/pip3 - but no luck.

How can I obtain the correct curses so I can rebuild python3.6 and it will function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses

> The curses module provides **an interface** to the **curses library**…

That is, you need a curses library in your system. To recompile Python you also need header (include) files from development package.

```
sudo yum install ncurses-devel
```

Comment: Many thanks, I was attempting to re-build 3.6.4, but was failing to reinstall the virtual environment. Grabbing ncurses-devel and rebuilding/reinstalling the venv worked.